# How do you read IIS configuration from a WiX burn custom bootstrapper?

Tags: iis, wix, burn

We've written a custom bootstrapper application to configure our program on install and to share configuration to multiple applications that it bundles. One of the things we'd like to add to it is the ability to select a website from IIS to install an application to. In order to do that, we're making use of Microsoft.Web.Administration to read the IIS configuration. However, on machines where UAC is enabled, any attempt to read the IIS configuration is denied with insufficient permissions.

It looks like the answer to this would be to somehow get the bootstrapper running with elevated permissions. However, all I've found so far is admonishments against using elevated bootstrapper applications. If the bootstrapper isn't to be run elevated, how do we read IIS configuration?